# How to add margin inside a HorizontalScrollView

Tags: android, xml, scrollview

I want to make a `HorizontalScrollView` that have a text inside and a scroll bar that is always shown. However, the scroll bar is overlapping with the text, how can I add margin inside the `HorizontalScrollView`

I've tried using `android:marginBottom="5dp"` but instead it gives the margin to the outside of the `HorizontalScrollView`

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/hsvP1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvPerulanganForPenjelasan"
    android:fadeScrollbars="false"
    android:scrollbarSize="5dp"
    android:marginBottom="5dp">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tvPerulanganForPenjelasan1"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:fontFamily="monospace"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:text="@string/for1"
        />
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

I expect to have the scroll bar at the bottom of the text, but still inside the `HorizontalScrollView`, but the result is the scroll bar is still overlapping with the text

Comment: Add `paddingBottom` to `TextView` instead

Answer (score -1):

You could change the layout_height of the HorizontalScrollView from "wrap_content" to a dimension greater than the TextView content height.